# Is it possible to work on strength and power on the same day?

Tags: strength, strength-training, power

I read Triphasic Training by Cal Dietz and he mentioned that you should only be training one parameter at a time.  First work on increasing absolute strength for 6 weeks (w/ weight 80% of 1RM).

After increasing absolute strength you should start working on power (w/ weight 55-70% of 1RM).

He mentions that you shouldn't be working on absolute strength and power simultaneously.  Is this correct?

Can I work on Strength on Monday & Wednesday, then work on Power on Friday?  Or can I even work on strength & power in the same workout?

This is for basketball players, if that helps.

Comment: "If you chase two rabbits at once, you will not catch either one." You probably can but often times in fitness focusing on one goal at a time will lead to more optional results in the long run.

Comment: @DeeV that doesn't really hold true with strength and power though, where DUP tends to do at least as well as linear or block periodisation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I read (1) Dietz advocates French contrast training, which consists of 4 exercises performed one after another:

- Heavy compound (80-90% 1RM)
- A plyometric jump
- A drop set or weighted jump (30% 1RM)
- Plyometric or accelerated plyometric

There is another simpler variation of this which uses only the two first exercises called complex training. From what I understand French contrast is best suited for advanced athletes and complex training best suited for medium advanced athletes.
I am guessing your athletes are not advanced but high school age kids?
If so complex training, that is pairing one heavy exercise with a plyometric variation of the same movement pattern, may be more appropriate (2), (4).

An example of such a complex pair (2) may be:

- 5 heavy back squats
- 3 minutes rest
- 10 box jumps
- 2 minutes rest

Repeat for a total of 3 sets (pairs).

Cal Dietz himself seems to be in favour of complex training:
"The complex and French contrast training is some of the most effective transfer from weight room methods to the field." (3).

(1) [French contrast training for rapid gains in speed and power](https://rugbystrengthcoach.com/french-contrast-training-rapid-gains-speed-power/)

(2) [The Effects of Complex Training in Male High School Athletes on the Back Squat and Vertical Jump](http://article.sapub.org/10.5923.j.sports.20170702.05.html)

(3) [Interview with Cal Dietz: Complex Training and Accelerated Plyometrics](https://www.just-fly-sports.com/interview-with-cal-dietz-complex-training-and-accelerated-plyometrics/)

(4) [How to Increase Power with Complex Training](https://blogs.gopherperformance.com/2019/05/complex-training/)

Answer (score 4):

> He mentions that you shouldn't be working on absolute strength and power simultaneously. Is this correct?

A reasonable way of interpreting this would be to take it as merely meaning that his specific program doesn't aim to train absolute strength and power simultaneously.

> Can I work on Strength on Monday & Wednesday, then work on Power on Friday? Or can I even work on strength & power in the same workout?

Yes, both of these are very common. Training for different adaptations on different days of the week is often referred to as daily undulating periodisation (DUP), and typically incorporates separate strength, power, and hypertrophy/endurance days. Training for different adaptations within the same workout is often known as 'pyramid' (hypertrophy first, strength last) or 'reverse pyramid' (strength first, hypertrophy last) training.